# View for content type detail pages

Tags: views

I created 2 different content type

- polls
- questions

Authenticate user can add them.
When user add any of the content.
we get urls like

node/3

node/4

I want to use view to have different designs on these pages.
But when I create a view with the page node/%

it is implementing same design on both of the content type.

Is there a way I can achieving this?

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you tried adding node/content type field in views to make sure the content you're shown is of type polls / questions?

Comment: Yes, but this is not working. It then show the design for poll. But empty page for the other content types.

Comment: Are you rendering fields or full content / teaser? If you're rendering fields, you'll have to make sure that other content type fields are also added in views.

Comment: I am rendering fields